# Can somebody find the syntax error

Tags: android, syntax-error

just cant seem to resolve this syntax error, maybe because i have already been too long in front of the screen. Please help!

```
package com.example.facilietiesreviewapp;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);
    addListenerOnButton();
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    final Context context = this;

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addStationBtn);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AddStationActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);   

        }


    }); /*SEMICOLON ERROR-Syntax error, insert "}" to complete 
  MethodBody*/
```

This is ↑where the error is, i've got the semicolon above underlined in red.

```
     //Search button link
     public void addListenerOnButtonSearch() {

        final Context context = this;

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startSearchBtn);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, SearchActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);   

            }

        }); 
    //Search button link

   }

}
```

Comment: did you just choose not to read the error or something? it tells you that you need an end bracket to complete the method

Answer (score 2):

you are not closing `addListenerOnButton` method before start  `public void addListenerOnButtonSearch()`

so put a } after `}); /*SEMICOLON ERROR-Syntax error, insert "}" to complete 
  MethodBody*/`

Answer (score 0):

Your `addListenerOnButton` method is not closed, there should be a `}` bracket in the end.